# The expo sdk requires expo to run. it appears the native expo modules are unavailable

Tags: react-native

I am getting a red screen with the error "the expo SDK requires expo to run. it appears the native expo modules are unavailable"

I have changed 
 "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",

to

"react-native": "0.57.5",

Comment: That’s not going to work with an expo app. You can’t change the version of react-native if you are using expo. You should change it back, or if you want you can eject your app so that you are using a full react-native app with access to the native modules.

Comment: Also make sure that your expo-cli version should also match with your expo version